# How to detect when a new task is created with Clickup API

Tags: python, integration, eventtrigger, clickup-api

Zappier is a little limited so I will adapt clickupython( https://github.com/Imzachjohnson/clickupython) to my needs, and I would like to know what is the proper way to trigger an event when a new task is created, what I think I could do is to polling a certain list and check if there are tasks with a newer compared to a date I have saved when I know I have already checked all the tasks.

That is my idea, but I don't know if it is the best way to do it.

UPDATE:
for example, I have a zap that when I create a new task in ClickUp the zap triggers an event that sends a message to a Slack channel. my question is how does zappier know when I create a task? or rather How can I replicate it with python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my question, hope you understand now, let me know if you don't

Comment: Zapier utilizes ClickUp's webhooks. You can think of a webhook as a reverse API call where instead of polling, the service send you an API call when an event occurs. In your example, you'd set-up a webhook for the "taskCreated" event. Please refer to the ClickUP API docs and this Zapier blog post on webhooks for more details: https://zapier.com/blog/what-are-webhooks/